# How to return a boolean?

Tags: python, return

I'm trying to test a function. It has to take 3 numbers, a, b and c as its arguments and to return a boolean which indicates whether a² = b²+c².

```py
a = int(input("a:"))
b = int(input("b:"))
c = int(input("c:"))

def test_pythagore():
    a**2 == b**2 + c**2

    return test_pythagore `
```

I'd like the program to return true or false as a boolean without writing it with print.

Comment: What is it returning?

Answer (score 3):

You have to return the actual outcome of your comparison and provide your function with the correct inputs.

```
def test_pythagore(a, b, c):
    return a**2 == b**2 + c**2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass parameters to function so she knows what does she operate with:

```
def test_pythagore(a, b, c):
```

this defines a function with 3 parameters.

Now you check if our condition is true and **store the result** to a variable so you can return it later.

```
def test_pythagore(a, b, c):
   result = c**2 == a**2 + b**2
   return result
```

*note: you could return the statement by itself but seeing you have problems with this, let's stick to returning variable*

So the whole code looks like this:

```
def test_pythagore(a, b, c):
   result = c**2 == a**2 + b**2
   return result

# you chose to round to ints, why not
a = int(input("a:")) 
b = int(input("b:")) 
c = int(input("c:"))

variable = test_pythagore(a, b, c)
print(variable)  # prints True or False
```

Seeing your code you should probably try some tutorial, thankfully official python docs offer such a thing!
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```py
    a = int(input("a:"))
    b = int(input("b:"))
    c = int(input("c:"))

    def test_pythagore(a,b,c):
        return a**2 == b**2 + c**2

    test_pythagore(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to change. Your function has to have the arguments provided as parameters. You can read up on how functions work here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp.

The code below will run the function and store the boolean value in a variable called result:

```
a = int(input("a:"))
b = int(input("b:"))
c = int(input("c:"))

def test_pythagore(a,b,c):
    return a**2 == b**2 + c**2

result = test_pythagore(a,b,c)
```